# Probability Mass Function and CDF of a function with random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, education

I am trying to solve this type of problems for my next exam. The problem goes something like this.
Let X be a random variable with density of $$p(x)=\frac{1}{8}(x+2) , x\in(-2,2)$$
$$\text{and}$$ $$p(x)=0 ,\text{ otherwise}$$

Let  $$Y=3X\ \text{ and }\ Z=1-X^{2}.$$  I have to find the **CDF** and **PDF** of both of the this functions of random variables.

In the books with examples i have i find 2 ways of solving this examples.

**First method** is: if the function is monotonously increasing then I have to  find the inverse function and plug it in

$$P(\text{ inverse function })\cdot|(\text{derivative of inverse})|.$$

**The second method** i find is that i should do the $$P(Y<y)=P(1-X^{2}<y)=1-P(X^{2}<1-y)=1-P\left(X<\pm\sqrt{1-y}\right)=\cdots$$

After this i cannot determinate the bounds of the integral of the density function.

Comment: So for the CDF and the PDF (density function) do i use the density of x with this new bounds of z (-3:1]. Integration from -3 to 1 of the 1/8(x+2) @GrahamKemp

Answer (score 0):

That's 
$\mathsf P(Z<z)~{=\mathsf P(1−X^2<z)\\=\mathsf P(X^2>1−z) \\ =\mathsf P(X<−\sqrt{1−z}\cup X>+\sqrt{1-z}) \\ = 1-\mathsf P({-}\sqrt{1-z}\leqslant X\leqslant {+}\sqrt{1-z})}$

and if $X∈(−2;0)∪[0;2)$ then $1−X^2∈\big(1−(−2)^2;1-0^2\big)\cup\big(1-2^2;1-0^2\big]$.   In other words, the support for $X$ is *folded* onto the support for $Z$ (which comlicates the first method; the function is not invertable).

Further, the integration region we're most interested in is $X\in[-\sqrt{1-z};0)∪[0;+\sqrt{1-z})$

By the second method, the CDF is: $$F_Z(z) ~=~ {{\left(1-\int_{-\sqrt{1-z}}^{\sqrt{1-z}}\dfrac{(x+2)\operatorname d x}8\right) \mathbf 1_{z\in(-3;1]}}}+{\mathbf 1_{z\in(1;\infty)}}$$

To find the pdf you can take the unsigned differential of this integral, or apply the first method (which is the same result without the differentiate-an-integral task).

$$f_Z(z) ~=~ {{\dfrac{(2-\sqrt{1-z})}{8}\cdot\begin{vmatrix}\dfrac{\mathrm d ({-}\sqrt{1-z})}{\mathrm d z\qquad}\end{vmatrix}\mathbf 1_{z\in(-3;1)}}+{\dfrac{(2+\sqrt{1-z})}{8}\cdot\begin{vmatrix}\dfrac{\mathrm d ({+}\sqrt{1-z})}{\mathrm d z\qquad}\end{vmatrix}\mathbf 1_{z\in(-3;1]}}}$$

Comment: Do i have to look in the both cases of z positive and z being negative? @GrahamKemp

Comment: No; the sign of the square root is handled in the bounds for the integral ... and in the fold summation for the Jacobian transformation.